# innerHTML not working in Cordova Android simulator

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, innerhtml

Even when I create a fresh HelloWorld project, and paste the code from w3school.
The problem is that the paragraph does not change.

```
<p id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below code.

```
 document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

If you are using Phonegap use deviceready event

```
    function myFunction() { ... }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        ...
        document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
        ...
    }

    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
```

Otherwise you can use jquery for the click event.

```
$("#demo").click(function () { myFunction(); });
```

Or

```
$("#demo").click(function () { 
    $(this).html("Paragraph changed!");
});
```